# CI load view via jquery

Tags: codeigniter

hi guys im loading popup screen in this way

```
<script>
  function show_popup(){
    $('#popup-container').load(html);
$('.popup').fadeIn();
  }
</script>
```

on my html

```
<a onlick="show_popup('popup/view-content')" href="#">
```

my problem is when the html was loaded the previous html loaded can be seen for awhile before the new one shows up.. how can i unload the previous html.

the view seems to cache displaying the previous html how can i erase the previous html then load the new one

Answer (score 0):

To remove caching from a page you need to include this at the top of your page:-

```
$this->output->set_header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"); 
$this->output->set_header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i(worry)") . " GMT"); 
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"); 
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: solution should be in jquery alone sir how to unload html via jquery

Comment: is this on the view of the page?

Comment: yeah you can also try  append a random number to your  URL. Like

<script src="https://www.mydomain.com/myjsfile.js?123456789"></script>